# Formatting Phone Numbers in WP Custom Post Type

Tags: php, string-formatting, phone-number

I have a custom post type called "contacts" and a meta-box input called "phone_number".

There are a bunch of different ways these phone numbers have been entered: ie. 1234567890 / 123-456-7890 / (123)456-7890 / 1-123-456-7890 / etc.

I want to add a function that removes all spaces, brackets and dashes, and produces a 10 digit string, or an 11 digit string (for long distance numbers with the +1 Country code at the beginning).

Once I have the number simplified to a 10 or 11 digit string, I want it to format accordingly:
10 digit - 123-456-7890
11 digit - 1-123-456-7890

I found one other thread that mentioned using this:

```
function format_phone($phone) {
    
    $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);
 
    if (strlen($phone) == 7)
        return preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "$1-$2", $phone);
    elseif (strlen($phone) == 10)
        return preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "($1) $2-$3", $phone);
    else
        return $phone;
}
```

But I can't seen to figure out where to add that, or what needs to be changed to make it work for my needs.

Comment: Is "WP" WordPress in this context, or Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1):

To replace anything that is not a digit you can use:

`$phone = preg_replace("/[^\d]*/","", $phone);`

But I'm sorry I can not help you with WordPress. I guess there is a hook on post submit ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function format_phone($phone) {
$phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);

if(strlen($phone) == 10)
    return preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "$1-$2-$3", $phone);
else if(strlen($phone) == 11)
    return preg_replace("/([0-9]{1})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "$1-$2-$3-$4", $phone);
else return false;

}
```

Comment: Where would I place this? In my template file or my functions file where my custom-post-type functions are located? Here's what I currently have in my template file:

    <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'phone_number', true) ) { ?>
    <strong>Phone Number: </strong>
    <?php $meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'phone_number', true ); // Retrieves the stored value from the database
         if( !empty( $meta_value ) ) { // Checks and displays the retrieved value
    echo $meta_value;
    }
    ?>
    <?php } ?>